# Why doesn't async pipe detect changes in Angular (but subscription in component.ts does)?

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx, async-pipe

I'm using an async pipe in angular to monitor an observable coming from an rxjs store. The component's ngOnInit looks like this

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.userRole$ = this.store.select(selectUserProfile).pipe(
    filter(user => !!user),
    map(user => parseUserRole(user.role))
  );
}
```

The component template looks like this

```html
<p> User role is {{ userRole$ | async }} </p>
```

After the user logs in, the message on the page remains an empty string

In the component.ts I added the following the code to debug the issue

```js
this.userRole$.subscribe(userRole => {
  alert(`new user role is ${userRole}`);
});
```

After the user logs in, I get an alert saying "new user role is admin", however, the pipe in the html template doesn't update.

When I replaced the store select() with a dummy value using of() and everything worked as expected, so I'm pretty sure the problem is something to do with rxjs.

The auth reducer (which is firing) looks like this (

```js
export function reducer(state = initialAuthState, action: AuthActions): AuthState {
    switch (action.type) {
        /// ...CODE OMITTED
        case AuthActionTypes.UserProfileRetrieved:
            alert(`setting user profile ${action.payload.userProfile}`)
            return { ...state, userProfile: action.payload.userProfile }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

I've tried making sure the UserProfileRetrieved action is dispatched from inside ngZone.run() but that didn't make difference. I don't really know how else to go about debugging this. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: If you can add `tap` operator to the pipeline it will be a good debugging point and if you can provide a `stackblitz` with the example it will be great!

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response! I added a tap() operator and the details were logged as expected.  I can confirm that the observable is working, but the problem seems to be something to do with the async pipe... I can't make a stackblitz, unfortunately, as this problem only appears in a cordova project when using auth0. I tried reproducing the issue with a dummy observable using of() and it worked as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be caused by a side-effect of the auth0 native app login flow. The app router was configured to use hash-based routing in order to support Cordova. After getting the login token from auth0, we were clearing the hash to remove the token information. Any store updates after this point were not being reflected in the async pipes, but updates before this were.

If anyone is having a similar problem make sure that **clearing the hash is the last thing you do before navigating to the post authorization URL**. Thanks @Shorbagy and @KShewengger for your help.

Here's the code I used to do this

```js
@Effect()
    loginComplete$ = this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType<LoginComplete>(AuthActionTypes.LoginComplete),
        exhaustMap(() => {
            return this.authService.authResult$.pipe(
                map((authResult: any) => {
                    if (environment.platform.name === Platforms.BROWSER) {
                        window.location.hash = '';
                    }

                    if (authResult && authResult.accessToken) {
                        this.authService.setAuth(authResult);
                        return new LoginSuccess();
                    } else {
                        debugger;
                        return new LoginFailure({ message: 'no accessToken', payload: authResult })
                    }
                }),
                catchError(error => of(new LoginFailure(error)))
            );
        })
    );
```

Comment: May I ask how you `cleared` the hash ?

Comment: @Stephane Edited the answer to include the code. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this code and see if it works fine. Have added tap operator to see if such changes/data emitted from the store took place.

```
this.userRole$ = this.store
   .select(selectUserProfile)
   .pipe(
     tap(user => console.log('FETCHED:', user)),        // Console if user data exists
     filter(Boolean),                                   // Change !!user to Boolean
     tap(user => console.log('FILTERED:', user)),       // Console if user exists after filter 
     map(user => parseUserRole(user.role))
     tap(user => console.log('MAPPED:', user)),         // Console if user is mapped
   );
```

> NOTE:
>
> That the store will only send it's response once the prior/parent service is invoked.

Example:

```
// If along with the getUsers() functionality has a piped storeService in it
// http.get(url).pipe(tap(data => this.storeService.set('users', data)))
this.userService.getUsers().subscribe();    

// You can then initialize your store to get the data invoked/set above
this.user$ = this.store.select('users');
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I've added those tap() operators and get the following output.

FETCHED: null
FETCHED: null
FETCHED: null
FETCHED: { ... } 
FILTERED: { ... }
MAPPED: { ... }
FETCHED: { ... } 
FILTERED: { ... }
MAPPED: { ... }
FETCHED: { ... } 
FILTERED: { ... }
MAPPED: { ... }

There are three pipes on the template which is why everything appears to firing three times. Everything in the pipeline seems to be working fine, it just seems that for some reason the pipe operator isn't picking up the latest changes from the store. I'm really stumped on where to go from here,,,

Comment: Can you place on "ngAfterViewInit" instead of "ngOnInit", im guessing that your store isn't ready/initialized yet and see if it has a data on it?